# Force store-level values via php instead of default

Tags: product, api, product-attribute, store-view

We have an API we use for an app in the iOS/Android store, and for the most part works fine.

However, our client has edited products so that there are values in the DEFAULT level that are different than the STORE view.

Is there a way via PHP to force the models/queries to load the STORE level values, and not the DEFAULT?

Comment: I don't understand exactly in which case you want to do that. Do you have custom model writen for your api or you use default api to get products?

Comment: We've built a specific app that has certain requirements, and for some reason our client has different values and doesnt want to go through 1000's of products to change them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For single products:

```
$product->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
```

For collections:

```
$collection->setStoreId($storeId)->load();
```